# Monitor Multiple exception in single catch in jdk 1.6

Tags: java, exception

Is there any alternative in java to make code possible in jdk1.6. I know same is possible in jdk 1.7, but i am stuck with jdk1.6.

Below code can catch multiple exceptions and i want to handle these exception and add it to database table. Since for all 3 exceptions, my exception handling logic is going to remain same. I don't want repeat same code for multiple catch blocks.

```
try{
      //do somthing here
    }catch(CustomException1 ex1 | CustomException2 ex2 | CustomException3 ex3){
          // Here goes common Exception handing logic.

   }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for the new pattern to be added suggests that it was something that was not easy to do before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax was added in Java 1.7 because it was difficult to do it cleanly before.

There are a few things you can do:

- Use a single catch for a common base class of CustomExceptionX (usually Exception, but sometimes you have to go up to Throwable if one of these is actually an Error). The drawback is that it will also catch RuntimeExceptions, so you will have to do a runtime check like Subin suggests. If you are the one defining the CustomExceptionX, you can define a common superclass for this usage and you won't have to do a runtime check.
- Put your common logic in a function and call this function in both catches. This way the only duplication will be the call to the function.

Answer (score 7):

```
try{
  //do somthing here
}catch(Exception e){
     if(e instanceof CustomException1 || e instanceof CustomException2  || e instanceof    CustomException3 ) {
      // Here goes common Exception handing logic.
      } else { throw e;}
```

}

There is no other option I think.

Comment: There is no capital O in instanceof keyword

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in the jdk1.6. I have just found an alternative. what you can do is define a class level variable.

```
   Object c ;
```

then in your corresponding catch block assign the reference.

```
   catch(CustomException1 cx1) {
    c= cx1;
   }

   catch(CustomException2 cx2){
    c = cx2;
    }

  if( c instanceof cx1 || c instanceof cx2) 

  // put your common logic here
```

i hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally went ahead with this code,

```
  try{ 
      //do somthing here 
    }catch(SuperExceptionClass ex){ 

     if (ex instanceof CustomException1 || ex instanceof CustomException2 ||  ex instanceof CustomException2) { 
         // Here goes common Exception handing logic.
     } else { 
         throw ex;
     }

   }
```